# How to remove empty values in excel chart when dates are not empty?

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart with two types of graphs. One shows number of items ordered and the second one - damaged items rate for each order. For the first graph I use bar chart, for the second dot chart. The question is how to remove empty/zero values in dot chart? "Hide empty values" doesn't work because date column is filled and used for bar chart.

Here is the data:

[image]

Here is the chart:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TL;DR*** (most likely) you are returning a `=""` for a blank cell, you need to return `#N/A`.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this issue depending on how you chart is setup.

**Defaults**

First, by default, Excel will not plot a cell that is truly empty. If I just create a chart (bar, scatter, line, etc.) and delete a data point, it will be removed from the chart, not set to 0.  This depends on the `Hidden and Empty` setting which defaults to `Gaps`.

[image]

[image: hidden and empty settings]

**What goes wrong**

So if you are seeing a data point for a blank cell, it means one of a couple things:

- The setting was changed for the chart on how to handle `Hidden and empty cells`
- **The cell is not truly empty**.  This is possible if you have a formula that returns `""`.  This will show as a 0 regardless of the `Hidden and empty` setting because it is not an empty cell.

[image]

**How to fix**

To resolve this issue then requires one of the following changes:

- Completely delete the cell contents so that it is truly an empty cell.  This assumes that the `Hidden and empty cells` option is at the default of `Gaps`.
- Have your formula return an `#N/A` and the chart will hide the data point regardless of any other settings.

[image]

- Change the `Hidden and empty cells` setting to `Gaps` (instead of `Zero`).  This will not affect the bar chart.  It will only serve to hide the missing entries on the dot plot.  This only works if the cell is truly empty.