# Excel named range used in chart

Tags: excel

I have defined a named range and used it to feed data in a chart in excel. The data will start from row 11 (column B) and may reach until row 500, but usually it doesn't expands further than row 75. Some entries initially usually are #N/A. So, the first are #N/A, some data follows and then blank.

The problem is that sometimes the data is plotted correctly (i.e. only the data are picked and plotted, leaving out #N/A), but there are times that I get an empty chart, even if the #N/A are followed by numbers. I would like to leave #N/A in, because if I replace them by blank, the chart picks the blanks as zero and I don't want that.

In column A I have another named range that keeps the years, which are used as the x-axis for the chart. So, as example, my dataset looks like that: in column A from row 11 to 31 I have the years 1990-2010, in column B from row 11 to 18 I have #N/A, and from 19 to 31 numbers. After row 31 there are empty cells. Let's assume that is imported correctly in the chart. Then if I change the data in column with #N/A expanding now until e.g. B22, I get an empty chart. when I check the chart , it seems that it picked the data until eg B20, so I get an empty chart.

I suspect it has to do with the way I defined the range, but I cannot find a solution.
 Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: edited. thanks for the comment/suggestion.

Comment: Can you add in a picture of the chart and an example of how this is going wrong?  It might also be useful to add a picture of the series formula or the actual formula for the chart (it's in the formula bar when you select the chart... it'll say `=SERIES(...)`).  There should not be anything special about the named range with respect to how it plots values (`#N/A` or blank).  A somewhat related question was asked yesterday regarding blanks in charts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043236/how-to-remove-empty-values-in-excel-chart-when-dates-are-not-empty/31053732#31053732

Comment: Thanks byron, I solved the problem, I will take a look at the related question you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. The problem was caused by a problem in the named range definition. What happens is the following. Assume you have a column with 5 #N/A on top and 10 values after the #N/As (a column with 15 cells). when I defined the named range, excel counts the number of cells in the column, but it doesn't take into consideration the #N/As, so it counts 10 cells (instead of 15). When you try to plot the series (having used the named range to get a dynamic chart), excel starts the chart from the beginning of the column, i.e. from the first #N/A. It remembers that it has counted 10 values for the series, so it plots the first 5 #N/As and then the first 5 'true' values, omitting the other 5 values.

In my case, I had the following code to define the named range :

```
=OFFSET(sheet1!$AP$10,0,0,COUNT(sheet1!$AP:$AP)
```

which started from line 10 at column AP.

In order to fix the problem with the #N/As on top, we simply have to count the number of N/As and add them back:

```
=OFFSET(sheet1!$AP$10,0,0,COUNT(sheet1!$AP:$AP)+COUNTIF(sheet1!$AP:$AP,#N/A))
```

and the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Byron, I tried it but it didn't work for me, but it might work for others.